# Configuracion TomCat Netbeans Local

Tags: java, netbeans

Actualmente me descarge la version de netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La version que trae Apache Tomcat , una vez esto me dirijo al netbans a crear un proyecto WEB , Elijo Apache TomCat
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo cual me trae a esta pantalla de configuracion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi objetivo es trabajar en local , pero intente con

> localhost y localhost:8080

Que deberia poner aqui para poder trabajar localmente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el IDE de desarrollo **Netbeans**, nos posicionamos en la pestaña **Services** y en *Servers* agregamos uno nuevo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccionamos **Apache Tomcat or TomEE** que es el tipo de servidor que vamos a agregar...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En *Server Location* introducimos el directorio donde esta instalado el **Apache Tomcat** y le creamos un usuario para acceder suponiendo que no le hallas ya editado uno manualmente en el *tomcat-users.xml* del conf en **Apache Tomcat**, en caso de haberlo hecho solo tenemos que desmarcar la casilla de *Create user* y tecleamos las credenciales de un usuario que tenga entre sus roles el de *manager-script*.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya lo que nos queda es comprobar para eso ejecutamos el servidor desde el **netbeans**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si esta correctamente instalado el **Apache Tomcat** te debe de dar una salida como esta...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya podemos crear nuestros sitios y aplicaciones web en JSP con Netbeans....

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que descargar un Tomcat de [su web](https://tomcat.apache.org/), copiarlo en una carpeta de tu disco y, en la última pantalla de configuración que has copiado, indicar la ruta en `Server location`

Una vez hecho eso, desde NetBeans haces botón derecho->deploy, botón derecho->run, y se debería abrir un navegador con tu aplicación.

Comment: pero al version full ya no deberia traer el tomcast?

Comment: No sé qué te has bajado, pero ahí te falta poner la ruta al tomcat